# Refresh web page exactly once without glitching

Tags: javascript

I would like to use javascript to refresh a web page exactly once. I have tried various codes on the web that are able to accomplish the task. However, I would like to refresh exactly once where no content is shown until the refresh occurs. This way; the user doesn't think a refresh happened, and it looks as if the site is taking a while to load. Is this possible?

Here is the code I am using.

```
window.onload = function() {
if(!window.location.hash) {
    window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
    window.location.reload();
}
}
```

I am wondering if the page can reload just as it does, but nothing is made visible to the user until the reload is finished.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions here. Start by posting some code that does not do exactly what you want. Then help us help you by telling us exactly WHY you want to refresh. Perhaps you have an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - if not perhaps you are trying to click spam?

Comment: You will always notice a refresh, triggered by `window.location.reload()`, so it's unclear what you mean with: "user doesn't think a refresh happened". But explain what you're trying to do a bit more and show us some code. If you use ajax requests, there are better solutions than reloading, but we have to know first what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am sorry I was unclear. What I want to do probably can't happen, but I thought I'd ask anyway. Thank you for taking the time to write to me.

Comment: You need to take the code out of onload since that triggers AFTER the page loaded

Comment: That does it. Thank you. Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Why would you _need_ a refresh anyway? Except in the case of forwarding, refreshes are not necessary anymore as pages can change their contents using JS...

Comment: You don't need a refresh to edit the hash. Just change the hash with an onload `window.location.hash = "#loaded"` if setting an initial hash is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the code out of onload since that triggers AFTER the page loaded

This is the closest you can get with the code you posted

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
if(!window.location.hash) { location.replace(window.location + '#loaded'); }
</script>
```